# How to Group list into sublist in a backward manner

Tags: python-3.x, list

What is the simplest and reasonably efficient way to slice a list into a list of the sliced sub-list sections in a reverse manner?

Here is the portion of my code that groups list into sublist:

```
binary1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
process1 = [binary1[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binary1), 4)]
print(process1)

Result: [[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1]]
```

However the result above is really not what I want is it will group in a reversal way, here is the result that I expected/want:
**Result: [[1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]**

I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: What's `binary1`, please?

Comment: @ggorlen hi the user input. it is saved in a list. and let's us say the user input is [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

Comment: Thanks. Looking at it further, I don't see any pattern in your desired output relative to the output you're getting. Can you edit your post with sample input/output and what exactly the transformation you want done is?

Comment: @ggorlen hi! i already edit my post. hope you could already understand it. thank you!

Comment: No, I still don't understand what the transformation "group in a reversal way" is, but there's an answerer who does. Good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binary1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

rest = len(binary1) // 4

print([binary1[:rest-1]] + [binary1[i:i+4] for i in range(rest-1, len(binary1), 4)])
```

Will print:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```